# Does DocumentDB support All Joins?

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

I'm sure DocumentDB does officially support "joins". But does this mean it support all types of Joins ?

one more point can we perform joins over two documents which is present in two different collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DocumentDB only supports intra-document joins, more as a way to format the output. The only way to do cross-document joins directly in DocumentDB is to implement them yourself with (an) additional round trip(s).

It's more work on your part, but it has the potential to be more performant than native SQL joins since you have knowledge about the nature of the data that a database optimization algorithm will not. Most people think of joins in SQL as close to free since they are so easy to write, but they can be a huge drain on performance. Also, cross-document consistency is traded off in most NoSQL databases for scalability. That said, DocumentDB's stored procedures gives you cross-document consistency. Nice!

Comment: Thank you for your response.@Larry Maccherone